# Why isn't energy conserved in time-ordered diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, interactions, virtual-particles

I'm new to particle physics, and I'm reading chapter 5 of Prof. Mark A. Thompson's "Modern Particle Physics", which talks about Time-ordered perturbation theory vs QED. However, in page 119 he wrote:

> By expressing the interaction in terms of the exchange of a virtual particle with four-momentum $q$, both
>   momentum and energy are conserved at the interaction vertices of a
>   Feynman diagram. **This is not the case for the individual time-ordered diagrams,
>   where energy is not conserved at a vertex**

The same thing is mentioned in the [slides accompanying this chapter, at page 6.](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/partIIIparticles/handouts/Handout_3_2011.pdf) My question is: how exactly is energy not conserved in the vertices of the 2 diagrams? And shouldn't this be a red flag, considering that the exchanging particles are "on mass-shell" (meaning they are physical? I'm not entirely sure yet).

Thank you!

Book:
[image]

Slide:
[image]

Comment: I think the need for a sum to end up with the usual feynman diagram, as seen in the last part of the copy, gives a clue . It is feynman diagrams that give the correct calculations. I also am waiting for  a clear  answer to this.