# Energy and momentum conservation on a vertex in a time-ordered diagram and in a Feynman diagram

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

I read in the book Modern particle physics(page 114-119) from Mark Thomson that for a time-ordered diagram, the energy at each vertex is not conserved, but the momentum is. Furthermore, the energy-momentum relation applies to the intermediate particle X, which is on mass-shell.

On the other hand if we sum over all the Feynman diagrams(which I suppose should be of the same order), then the four-momentum at the vertices is conserved, but now the energy-momentum relation does not apply to the exchanging particle anymore, which is now off mass-shell.

Can anyone please explain why these should be the case? I could not find any explanation in the book except that the energy conservation in the latter case is violated due to the energy-time uncertainty principle - but then again, why can momentum be conserved without regards to the momentum-position uncertainty principle? And why are the exchange particles on mass-shell in the time ordered diagram, but off mass-shell in the sum of all diagrams?

Would be very grateful for clarification on this topic!

**Figure 5.4:**

[image: Two possible time-orderings for the process a + b → c + d.]

---

**Then he states that in a time-ordered diagram energy is not conserved but momentum is**

[image]

[image: Explanation of violation of energy conservation using uncertainty principle.]

[image: Energy is not conserved at vertex.]

---

**On page 119 he discusses the energy conservation for the sum of all diagrams:**

[image]

---

**Diagram 5.5:**

[image: Figure 5.5]

I have found similar questions here on PSE but there are no answers to those questions as well. [Question 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719830/on-energy-conservation-and-time-ordered-interaction-diagrams) and [Question 2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435928/why-isnt-energy-conserved-in-time-ordered-diagrams)